How to connect Snowflake with PySpark with Google Colab?
I am trying to connect to Snowflake with Pyspark on Google Colab.
Spark version  3.4
Scala version 2.12.17
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark import SparkConf

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("SnowflakeDataRead") \
    .config("spark.jars", "/content/spark-snowflake_2.12-2.12.0-spark_3.4.jar,/content/snowflake-jdbc-3.13.30.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

I'm always getting this error:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o353.load. : org.apache.spark.SparkClassNotFoundException: [DATA_SOURCE_NOT_FOUND] Failed to find the data source: net.snowflake.spark.snowflake. Please find packages at `https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html`.
I followed this steps https://medium.com/@shrutighoradkar101/snowspark-connection-bridging-pyspark-and-snowflake-for-efficient-data-processing-a2190fd7f3e2
And download the Jar files within the correct supported versions.

The author of medium article mentions using Spark on PC not google colab.
For colab, let you upload and adjust the file paths accordingly:

Upload

from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()


Verify file path

dir_list = os.listdir("/content") 
print(dir_list)


Make change .config() by the correct path


This error typically occurs when the required JAR files are not correctly loaded or specified.
Ensure JAR Files are Correctly Downloaded and Uploaded: Make sure that the JAR files spark-snowflake_2.12-2.12.0-spark_3.4.jar and snowflake-jdbc-3.13.30.jar are correctly downloaded and uploaded to your Google Colab environment.
Verify JAR File Paths:
import os
os.listdir('/content')


I was able to fix it! Just had to change the sfAccount value to the Locator Name which is shown in the picture below, after making the changes recommended by priyanshu de1 and Chi_Cong.


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
